# Phone number regular expression for UK and US phones

Tags: regex

Has anyone got a good regex that will match on both UK and USA numbers?

It would need to cater for uk prefixes like +44 and also the US equivalent.

Does anyone know of such an expression?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: Reference: [North American Numbering Plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_Numbering_Plan?title=North_American_Numbering_Plan)

Comment: Looking at both UK and US numbering systems and the rapidity at which both change (to accommodate for growing cities, new cell networks and such), I would recommend a very simple regex that checks for the country prefix (+44 or +1) and then x number of digits (officially up to 19 max, but extensions might add more).

Comment: This question comes up almost every week. Please do a search first.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to validate UK mobile numbers:

```
<?php
function valid_UK_mobile($gsm) {
    return preg_match("/^00447\d{9}$|^07\d{9}$|^447\d{9}$|^[+]447\d{9}$/", $gsm); // +447XXXXXXXXX, 447XXXXXXXXX, 07XXXXXXXXX, 00447XXXXXXXXX
}
echo (valid_UK_mobile("+447000000000") ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK') . '<br />'; //success
echo (valid_UK_mobile("447000000000") ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK') . '<br />'; //success
echo (valid_UK_mobile("07000000000") ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK') . '<br />'; //success
echo (valid_UK_mobile("00447000000000") ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK') . '<br />'; //success
echo (valid_UK_mobile("00440000000000") ? 'OK' : 'NOT OK') . '<br />'; // fail
?>
```

something weird with stackoverflow, the code - http://paste-it.net/public/o060a91/

Answer (score 0):

You could even use:

`^\s*\(?(020[7,8]{1}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9{2}[ ]?[0-9]{4})|(0[1-8]{1}[0-9]{3}\)?[ ]?[1-9]{1}[0-9]{2}[ ]?[0-9]{3})\s*$`

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=495

or

`^(?:(?<1>[(])?(?<AreaCode>[2-9]\d{2})(?(1)[)])(?(1)(?<2>[ ])|(?:(?<3>[-])|(?<4>[ ])))?)?(?<Prefix>[1-9]\d{2})(?(AreaCode)(?:(?(1)(?(2)[- ]|[-]?))|(?(3)[-])|(?(4)[- ]))|[- ]?)(?<Suffix>\d{4})(?:[ ]?[xX]?(?<Ext>\d{2,4}))?$`

http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=537

Answer (score 0):

Those RegEx patterns are way too short.

The RegEx pattern to check whether the geographic area code is valid and the number length is correct, runs to:

`2(?:0[01378]|3[0189]|4[017]|8[0-46-9]|9[012])\d{7}|
1(?:(?:1(?:3[0-48]|[46][0-4]|5[012789]|7[0-39]|8[01349])|21[0-7]|31[0-8]|[459]1\d|61[0-46-9]))\d{6}|1(?:
2(?:0[024-9]|2[3-9]|3[3-79]|4[1-689]|[58][02-9]|6[0-4789]|7[013-9]|9\d)|
3(?:0\d|[25][02-9]|3[02-579]|[468][0-46-9]|7[1235679]|9[24578])|
4(?:0[03-9]|[28][02-5789]|[37]\d|4[02-69]|5[0-8]|[69][0-79])|
5(?:0[1235-9]|2[024-9]|3[015689]|4[02-9]|5[03-9]|6\d|7[0-35-9]|8[0-468]|9[0-5789])|
6(?:0[034689]|2[0-35689]|[38][013-9]|4[1-467]|5[0-69]|6[13-9]|7[0-8]|9[0124578])|
7(?:0[0246-9]|2\d|3[023678]|4[03-9]|5[0-46-9]|6[013-9]|7[0-35-9]|8[024-9]|9[02-9])|
8(?:0[35-9]|2[1-5789]|3[02-578]|4[0-578]|5[124-9]|6[2-69]|7\d|8[02-9]|9[02569])|
9(?:0[02-589]|2[02-689]|3[1-5789]|4[2-9]|5[0-579]|6[234789]|7[0124578]|8\d|9[2-57]))\d{6}|1(?:
2(?:0(?:46[1-4]|87[2-9])|545[1-79]|76(?:2\d|3[1-8]|6[1-6])|9(?:7(?:2[0-4]|3[2-5])|8(?:2[2-8]|7[0-4789]|8[345])))|
3(?:638[2-5]|647[23]|8(?:47[04-9]|64[015789]))|
4(?:044[1-7]|20(?:2[23]|8\d)|6(?:0(?:30|5[2-57]|6[1-8]|7[2-8])|140)|8(?:052|87[123]))|
5(?:24(?:3[2-79]|6\d)|276\d|6(?:26[06-9]|686))|
6(?:06(?:4\d|7[4-79])|295[567]|35[34]\d|47(?:24|61)|59(?:5[08]|6[67]|74)|955[0-4])|
7(?:26(?:6[13-9]|7[0-7])|442\d|50(?:2[0-3]|[3-68]2|76))|
8(?:27[56]\d|37(?:5[2-5]|8[239])|84(?:3[2-58]))|
9(?:0(?:0(?:6[1-8]|85)|52\d)|3583|4(?:66[1-8]|9(?:2[01]|81))|63(?:23|3[1-4])|9561))\d{3}|
176888[234678]\d{2}|16977[23]\d{3}`

The above RegEx does not deal with Guernsey, Isle of Man or Jersey numbers.

There's also a lot more needed if you need to check UK wide, mobile, freephone, NGN and Premium Rate, and other numbers too.

Comment: That's not a regex, it's a parlor trick! :D  Do you actually use that monster in a production environment?

Comment: It's in libphonenumber, and it rejects numbers that are too short, too long, or use an area code that does not exist.

Comment: It's in libphonenumber, and it rejects number ranges that are too short, too long, or use an area code that does not exist.

Comment: That's 1,394 characters. It might as well be a private key. As a regular expression it's unmaintainable and incomprehensible. If this were free spaced with thorough documentation and reference links, maybe it could be a useful answer.